# how can i improve loop performance when using project macro?

Tags: vba, macros, ms-project

As you can read from the below VBA codes for Project2013, the loop of "for" takes about 50-80 seconds to complete when the number of tasks comes to more than 1000.  How can i improve the performance?  Is there an "array" method like excel VBA?  thanks for your help!

```
Sub Change_Color_By_Task_Status()


' Expand all sub tasks
    SelectSheet
    OutlineShowAllTasks
    SelectTaskField Row:=1, Column:="Name"

' Clear all fields color
    SelectSheet
    FontEx CellColor:=16
    SelectTaskField Row:=1, Column:="Name", RowRelative:=False


Dim tskt As Task
For Each tskt In ActiveProject.Tasks
If Len(tskt.Name) > 0 Then
  If Not tskt Is Nothing Then  
  If Not tskt.ExternalTask Then
    If Not tskt.Summary Then    
        Select Case tskt.Text1
            Case "Complete"
                SelectRow Row:=tskt.ID, RowRelative:=False
                'Font Color:=pjBlack
                FontEx CellColor:=pjGray
            Case "Yellow"
                SelectRow Row:=tskt.ID, RowRelative:=False
                'Font Color:=pjBlack
                FontEx CellColor:=pjYellow
            Case "Green"
                SelectRow Row:=tskt.ID, RowRelative:=False
                'Font Color:=pjBlack
                FontEx CellColor:=pjWhite
            Case "Red"
                SelectRow Row:=tskt.ID, RowRelative:=False
               'Font Color:=pjRed
               FontEx CellColor:=pjRed
            Case "Overdue"
                SelectRow Row:=tskt.ID, RowRelative:=False
               Font Color:=pjWhite
               Font32Ex CellColor:=192
        End Select
     End If 
     End If  
    End If  
    End If
Next tskt

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it is much quicker to use ms project built-in filters when working with the interface.

Have project add columns for External Task, Summary, and Text1. Then use Application.SetAutoFilter to filter out Summary=yes, ExternalTak=Yes, then filter out each Text1, SelectAll and set your formatting. Something like this:

```
Sub Change_Color_By_Task_Status()

    'Add columns to filter
    TableEditEx Name:="&Entry", TaskTable:=True, NewName:="", NewFieldName:="Text1", ColumnPosition:=0
    TableApply Name:="&Entry"
    TableEditEx Name:="&Entry", TaskTable:=True, NewName:="", NewFieldName:="External Task", Title:="", ColumnPosition:=0
    TableApply Name:="&Entry"
    TableEditEx Name:="&Entry", TaskTable:=True, NewName:="", NewFieldName:="Summary", Title:="", ColumnPosition:=0
    TableApply Name:="&Entry"

    'Filter out summaries and externals
    SetAutoFilter FieldName:="External Task", FilterType:=pjAutoFilterFlagNo
    SetAutoFilter FieldName:="Summary", FilterType:=pjAutoFilterFlagNo

    'Filter by Text1
    'for "Complete"
    SetAutoFilter FieldName:="Text1", FilterType:=pjAutoFilterCustom,     Test1:="equals", criteria1:="Complete"
    SelectAll
    '[Apply complete formatting]
    SetAutoFilter FieldName:="Text1", FilterType:=pjAutoFilterClear

    '... repeat for the other Text1 values

    'clear filters
    SetAutoFilter FieldName:="External Task", FilterType:=pjAutoFilterClear
    SetAutoFilter FieldName:="Summary", FilterType:=pjAutoFilterClear

    'Remove columns
    SelectTaskColumn Column:="Text1"
    ColumnDelete
    SelectTaskColumn Column:="Summary"
    ColumnDelete
    SelectTaskColumn Column:="External Task"
    ColumnDelete
End Sub
```

Hope this speeds it up

Comment: Thanks KainC, would you please give me more detailed steps on how to do so? I am a beginner of Project vba so I can't catch you quite well.

Comment: I added an outline of what it would look like

Comment: KainC,  where should i place the orignal codes, please?   after the Filter out summaries and externals?

Comment: Where it says [Apply complete formatting] add your Font / Font32Ex commands for "complete". Then copy the 5 or 6 lines from " 'for "complete"" to " 'repeat..." And change "criteria1" in the autoFilter to "Green" and apply green formatting. Repeat this for each color. It's just filtering by Text1, selecting everything, applying the font, and clearing the filter each time

Comment: Thank you KainC, your solution really makes sense!